# How to style React Native switch component?

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I'm making forms in React Native using tcomb-form-native (https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native) module. This module provides a boolean type of input, which renders a Switch component (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html).

Right now, I'm trying to style it, so the Switch would look like this: [image]

I'm not sure what would be the best way to achieve that? Using the switch component? using a fake component that triggers the real switch (which would be hidden)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way is to make a custom factory I made a custom switch once, I'll post it here. I did not modify the looks of the Switch but I'm confident you could create a component that looks like your image and then use it in your factory. In my case I aligned some text with the switch with a clickable link and so on. I have not tried it but i guess you can replace the Switch component with your own.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Switch, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';
import Strings from '../config/strings.js';

var Component = t.form.Component;

class TermsSwitch extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    var locals = super.getLocals();
  }

  getLocals () {
    var locals = super.getLocals();
    return locals;
  }

  getTemplate () {
    return function (locals) {
      var stylesheet = locals.stylesheet;
      var formGroupStyle = stylesheet.formGroup.normal;
      var controlLabelStyle = stylesheet.controlLabel.normal;
      var checkboxStyle = stylesheet.checkbox.normal;
      var helpBlockStyle = stylesheet.helpBlock.normal;
      var errorBlockStyle = stylesheet.errorBlock;

      if (locals.hasError) {
        formGroupStyle = stylesheet.formGroup.error;
        controlLabelStyle = stylesheet.controlLabel.error;
        checkboxStyle = stylesheet.checkbox.error;
        helpBlockStyle = stylesheet.helpBlock.error;
      }

      var label = locals.label ? <Text style={controlLabelStyle}>{locals.label}</Text> : null;
      var help = locals.help ? <Text style={helpBlockStyle}>{locals.help}</Text> : null;
      var error = locals.hasError && locals.error ? <Text accessibilityLiveRegion="polite" style={[errorBlockStyle, {marginTop: 2}]}>{locals.error}</Text> : null;

      return (
        <View style={formGroupStyle}>
          {label}
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}>Jag har läst och accepterar </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => locals.config.onPressTerms()}>
                <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', fontSize: 14, textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}>villkoren</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 6}}>
              <Switch
                accessibilityLabel={locals.label}
                ref="input"
                disabled={locals.disabled}
                onTintColor={locals.onTintColor}
                thumbTintColor={locals.thumbTintColor}
                tintColor={locals.tintColor}
                style={checkboxStyle}
                onValueChange={(value) => locals.onChange(value)}
                value={locals.value} />
            </View>
          </View>
          {help}
          {error}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default TermsSwitch
```

And then use your factory like:

```
const options = {
    fields: {
        your_switch: {
          config: {
            onPressTerms: () => {
              ...
            },
          },
          factory: TermsSwitch,
          stylesheet: stylesheet,
        },
        ...
    },
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Good luck!

Comment: For the moment, I ended up with full custom stuff. But I may need to use your answer, as it's definitely more reliable. I didn't know about `factory: TermsSwitch`